# LISP list of expressions

Tags: macros, lisp

I have a list of expressions that I want to evaluate in order inside a macro and return the value of the last one. I've tried this, but the compiler doesn't like it:

```
(defmacro foo lst-of-exprs
  ',@lst-of-exprs)
```

and

```
(defmacro foo lst-of-exprs
  '(progn ,@(lst-of-exprs))
```

Is there a way to do this without using a do loop?

Comment: "the compiler doesn't like it" What does that mean?

Comment: How are you planning to use your macro?  How does it differ from progn?

Comment: Can you give the error message?

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
(defmacro foo lst-of-exprs
  `(progn ,@lst-of-exprs))
```

although really this is just defining a synonym for `progn` itself.